# Find substring in Python

Tags: python, nltk

I have found synonyms of a word "plant"

```
syn = wordnet.synsets('plant')[0].lemmas()
>>>[Lemma('plant.n.01.plant'), Lemma('plant.n.01.works'), Lemma('plant.n.01.industrial_plant')]
```

and an input word

```
word = 'work'
```

I want to find if 'work' appears in syn. How to do it?

Comment: I'm not very sure what you require but try this: `from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn; wn.synsets('plant')[0].lemma_names()`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check for the presence of a substring using the keyword `in` in python:

```
>>> word = "work"
>>> word in 'plant.n.01.works'
True
>>> word in 'plant.n.01.industrial_plant'
False
```

If you want to test this in a list you can do a loop:

```
syn = ["plant.one","plant.two"]
for plant in syn:
    if word in plant:
        print("ok")
```

Or better a list comprehension:

```
result = [word in plant for plant in syn]
# To get the number of matches, you can sum the resulting list:
sum(result)
```

**Edit**: If you have a long list of words to look for, you can just nest two loops:

```
words_to_search = ["work","spam","foo"]
syn = ["plant.one","plant.two"]
for word in words_to_search_for:
    if sum([word in plant for plant in syn]):
        print("{} is present in syn".format(word))
```

---

Note that you are manipulating [Lemma](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html?highlight=lemma#nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Lemma) objects and not strings. You might need to check for `word in plant.name` instead of just `word` if the object do not implement the `[__contains__](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__contains__)` method. I am not familiar with this library though.

Comment: in works fine. but what if I want to search over 100 lemmas. I want a generic solution to it @Geeklhem

Comment: I added a paragraph, but I am not sure If I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

`Lemma`'s have a `name()` method so what you could do is

```
>>> 'works' in map(lambda x: x.name(), syn)
True
```

Edit: did not see you said "work", not works, so this would be:

```
>>> for i in syn:
...     if 'work' in i.name():
...             print True
... 
True
```

You can wrap it in a function for example.

Or a mixture of the two suggestions I made:

```
any(map(lambda x: 'work' in x, map(lambda x: x.name(), syn)))
```

Comment: Woww.. Python is so powerful OOoo.. Thnx @Alex Hristov. This works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
str1 = "this is a example , xxx"
str2 = "example"
target_len = len(str2)
str_start_position = str1.index(str2)  #or  str1.find(str2)
str_end_position = str_start_position + target_len
```

you can use str_start_position and str_end_position to get your target substring